# Getting Started With Akka Streams

Tags: scala, rx-java, akka-stream

I'v been reading about Akka Streams in the last couple of days and I've been working with Rx libraries in Scala for the last couple of months. To me there seems to be some overlap in what both these libraries got to offer. RxScala was a bit easier to get started, understand and use. For example., here is a simple use case where I'm using Scala's Rx library to connect to Kafka topic, wrap that up into an Observable so that I could have subscribers getting those messages.

```
val consumerStream = consumer.createMessageStreamsByFilter(topicFilter(topics), 1, keyDecoder, valueDecoder).head
val observableConsumer = Observable.fromIterator(consumerStream).map(_.message())
```

This is quite simple and neat. Any clues on how I should get started with akka streams? I want to use the same example above where I want to emit events from the Source. I will later have a Flow and a Sink. Then finally, in my main class, I will combine these 3 to run the application data flow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is what I came up with:

```
val kafkaStreamItr = consumer.createMessageStreamsByFilter(topicFilter(topics), 1, keyDecoder, valueDecoder).head
Source.fromIterator(() => kafkaStreamItr).map(_.message)
```